# Good OSGi tutorials

Tags: java, osgi

Do you know any good tutorial for OSGi? It should detail how it is used but also how it work internally and the different implementations and their differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good way to get started with OSGi in the way it was intended is with bndtools. Take a look at http://bndtools.org/doc/tutorials/components/ for more information.

Comment: Pater, that link is dead. Octopus attack!

Answer (score 3):

I personally can recommend you [OSGi and Equinox](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321585712) (it focuses on Equinox). I did not read it myself (yet), but [OSGi in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988916) looks promising.